# Need to count unique transactions by month but ignore records that occur 3 days after 1st entry for that ID

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with just two columns: User_ID and fail_date. Each time somebody's card is rejected they are logged in the table, their card is automatically tried again 3 days later, and if they fail again, another entry is added to the table. I am trying to write a query that counts unique failures by month so I only want to count the first entry, not the 3 day retries, if they exist. My data set looks like this

```
user_id  fail_date
222      01/01
222      01/04
555      02/15
777      03/31
777      04/02
222      10/11
```

so my desired output would be something like this:

```
month     unique_fails
jan       1
feb       1
march     1
april     0
oct       1
```

**I'll be running this in Vertica, but I'm not so much looking for perfect syntax in replies. Just help around how to approach this problem as I can't really think of a way to make it work. Thanks!**

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lag()` to get the previous timestamp per user. If the current and the previous timestamp are less than or exactly three days apart, it's a follow up. Mark the row as such. Then you can filter to exclude the follow ups.

It might look something like:

```
SELECT month,
       count(*) unique_fails
       FROM (SELECT month(fail_date) month,
                    CASE
                      WHEN datediff(day,
                                    lag(fail_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,
                                                         ORDER BY fail_date),
                                    fail_date) <= 3 THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END follow_up
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE follow_up = 0
       GROUP BY month;
```

I'm not so sure about the exact syntax in Vertica, so it might need some adaptions. I also don't know, if `fail_date` actually is some date/time type variant or just a string. If it's just a string the date/time specific functions may not work on it and have to be replaced or the string has to be converted prior passing it to the functions.

If the data spans several years you might also want to include the year additionally to the month to keep months from different years apart. In the inner `SELECT` add a column `year(fail_date) year` and add `year` to the list of columns and the `GROUP BY` of the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: The syntax is not right for Vertica but the answer does not deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag about whether this is a "unique_fail" by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(fail_date) over (partition by user_id order by fail_date) > fail_date - 3
             then 0 else 1
        end) as first_failure_flag
from t;
```

Then, you want to count this flag by month:

```
select to_char(fail_date, 'Mon'),  -- should aways include the year
       sum(first_failure_flag)
from (select t.*,
             (case when lag(fail_date) over (partition by user_id order by fail_date) > fail_date - 3
                   then 0 else 1
             end) as first_failure_flag
      from t
     ) t
group by to_char(fail_date, 'Mon')
order by min(fail_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), determine the **previous fail_date** (`prev_fail_date`), for a specific `user_id` and `fail_date`, using a [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html).
- Using the derived table `dt`, [Count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) the failure, if the difference of number of days between current `fail_date` and `prev_fail_date` is **greater than 3**.
- [DateDiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function alongside with [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function is used to determine the cases, which are not repeated tries.
- To `Group By` this result on Month, you can use [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.
- But then, the data **can** be from multiple years, so you need to separate them out **yearwise** as well, so you can do a multi-level group by, using [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function as well.

Try the following (in MySQL) - you can get idea for other RDBMS as well:

```
SELECT YEAR(dt.fail_date) AS year_fail_date, 
       MONTH(dt.fail_date) AS month_fail_date, 
       COUNT( IF(DATEDIFF(dt.fail_date, dt.prev_fail_date) > 3, user_id, NULL) ) AS unique_fails 
FROM (
       SELECT  
         t1.user_id, 
         t1.fail_date, 
         (
          SELECT t2.fail_date 
          FROM your_table AS t2 
          WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
            AND t2.fail_date < t1.fail_date 
          ORDER BY t2.fail_date DESC 
          LIMIT 1
         ) AS prev_fail_date 
       FROM your_table AS t1 
     ) AS dt 
GROUP BY 
  year_fail_date, 
  month_fail_date 
ORDER BY 
  year_fail_date ASC, 
  month_fail_date ASC
```